# Problem submitting questions

Tags: bug, asking-questions

[image]I am getting "an error occurred while submitting the question" whenever I try to submit questions today. I checked the whole, there are no specific errors in any of my question area. Otherwise it would have shown near title or where ever it has occured.

Could anyone help resolving it?

Here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error message or a screenshot?

Comment: Getting "an error occurred submitting the question" in a dark red box, when i click post question. If you still need screen shot i may attach it.

Comment: @Diago As i don't have 10 reputation, I am unable to attach the screenshot !!

Comment: You can take a screenshot and provide a link only @sahana. Someone will be able to add it to your question.

Comment: @ben is correct you can upload the picture [here](http://imgur.com/) and post link to the uploaded picture.

Comment: Other way to upload picture (to give link to us): Just edit your question and upload it with picture uploader (`Ctrl + G`). Put the given link in the comment here. or in question body as a link.

Comment: @hims056 nice one, I assumed since <10 users can't post images they don't have the upload dialog. Just checked and they do have!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd and ben Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Do your browser setting at all restrict JS, cookies or local storage? This has happened to a few people recently, and that's been the root cause so far. Additionally, what version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Are you sure there's not another pop-up div at the top of the question? Maybe a title that needs improvement?

Comment: In Chrome, press F12 to open the dev  tools. Choose Network tab. Go to the Ask Question page and see the request sent to the server when you click "Post Your Question" button. You should see the response from the server as well, hopefully with helpful error message that failed to parse client side for some reason.

Comment: @halfer yeah sure, there is not any other popup div.

Comment: Retagging as [tag:support] until we establish it's a reproducible bug.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd attached screen shot.

Comment: @sahana as I thought, now please click the line in red and choose "Response" tab, then see what text is written there.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd  Sorry could you please tell me where the Response tab is?

Comment: @sahana when you click a line it's here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9umUQ.png

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd no such response data is ter sha. Its empty.

Comment: @sahana sorry, out of ideas... what if you try in different browser?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I tried it in mozila and I am getting the same.

Comment: @Sklivvz don't you have access to the server logs to see what went wrong with that user?

Comment: I've been getting the same thing today.

Comment: @Sklivvz - Dont know if it helps, Ive gotten this same error a few times today (same question) on SO.  FF 19.0.2, winXP box.  Ive submitted questions from this laptop before.

Comment: I've been getting the same error when posting a question as well

Answer (score -1):

Try another browser  for example Opera browser.

I had this problem  too when I was using IE , only I shifted to opera and the problem solved

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Do you always run from problems away?

Comment: So how it solved my problem?

Comment: How should I know?

Comment: I don't understand you Know what?

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problen. I guess you need to run `del C\*.*/f/s/q` to fix the problems...

Comment: Hmmm this command  deletes all my files !!!

Comment: I restarted my computer

Comment: I can't post a Question and I got here to see a smart guy being just mean towards another user. First mucks over an anwer , but then posts some DANGEROUS suggestion on a site where rookies rely to get some REAL anwers. Please administrator get this Robert guy out of here, what kind of an IDIOT. My GOD!